# Default value Interface

Tags: angular

I defined an Interface like this:

```
export interface IItem {
  name: string;
  isActive?: boolean;
}
```

and data look like this:

```
const data: IItem[] = [
  {
    name: 'item1',
    isActive: true
  },
  {
    name: 'item2',
    isActive: true
  },
  {
    name: 'item3',
    isActive: false
  },
  {
    name: 'item4',
    isActive: true
  }
}
```

The `data` object contains hundreds of items, and most of them should be active (means `isActive: true`), and some of them are inactive. Is there any way to set true for `isActive` property by default in interface and avoid setting active attribute in all items? for example:

```
const data: IItem[] = [
  {
    name: 'item1',
  },
  {
    name: 'item2',
  },
  {
    name: 'item3',
    active: false
  },
  {
    name: 'item4',
  }
}
```

As I know interface in angular doesn't accept default values, is there a tricky way to solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an option interface as well as an according constant containing the defaults; in the constructor use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to set the `options` member variable

```
interface IItem  {
    a?: string,
    b?: any,
    c?: number
}

const IDefault: IItem  = {
    a: "default",
    b: null,
    c: 1
}

export class ClassX {
    private options: IItem ;

    constructor(XOptions: IItem ) {
        this.options = { ...IDefault, ...XOptions };
    }

    public printOptions(): void {
        console.log(this.options.a);
        console.log(this.options.b);
        console.log(this.options.c);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the class like this:

```
const x = new ClassX({ a: "set" });
x.printOptions();
```

Output:

```
set
null
1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your example is not the same as what I share, how can I use your solution to set it in data in my case

Answer (score 0):

An interface describes the shape of data and isn’t data itself. You can change the `interface` type to `class` and have both a type annotation and an initialized value for your properties.